# What happens to docker images pulled / run in gitlab CI?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm experiencing strange problem with gitlab CI build.

My script looks like that:

```
 - docker pull myrepo:myimage
 - docker tag myrepo:myimage myimage
 - docker run --name myimage myimage
```

It was working for a few times, but afterwards I've started getting errors:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name
>   "/myimage" is already in use by container ....

I've logged on the particular machine where that step was executed, and `docker ps -a` has shown, that the image was left on the build machine...

I've expected that gitlab CI build steps are fully separated from external environment via running them in docker containers... so that a build would not 'spoil' the environment for other builds. So I've expected all images and containers created by CI build to simply perish... which is not the case...

Is my gitlab somehow misconfigured, or this is expected behaviour, that docker images / containers exists in context of host machine and not within docker image?

In my build, I use image `docker:latest`

Comment: I would first stop everything before running - docker run just to make sure that I have a clean environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your Gitlab is not misconfigured. Gitlab does clean its runners and executors (the docker image you run your commands in).

Since you are using DinD (Docker-in-Docker) any container you start or build is actually build on the same host and runs besides your job executor container, not 'inside' it.

Therefore you should clean up, Gitlab has no knowledge of what you do inside of your job so its not responsible for it.

I run various pipelines with the same situation you described so some suggestions:

```
 job:
   script:
   - docker pull myrepo:myimage
   - docker tag myrepo:myimage myimage
   - docker run --name myimage myimage
   after_script:
   # Stop any running containers, if they are not running anymore (since its not a run -d), ignore errors about that.
   - docker rm -f myrepo:myimage myimage || true
   # Remove pulled images
   - docker rmi -f myrepo:myimage image
```

Also (and I don't know your exact job of course) this could be shorter:

```
 job:
   script:
   # Only pull if you want to 'refresh' any images that would be left behind
   - docker pull myrepo:myimage
   - docker run --name myimage myrepo:myimage
   after_script:
   # Stop any running containers, if they are not running anymore (since its not a run -d), ignore errors about that.
   - docker rm -f myrepo:myimage || true
   # Remove pulled image
   - docker rmi -f myrepo:myimage
```

Comment: The problem is, this is unstable. I start one container, than another job that connects with that container (for example, start containter DB for test). If that job fails, the script is stopped, and my docker rm / docker rmi will never run. And it is possible another build will be started paralelll on the same machine, causing name conflicts... Is there any general solution for this?